# SQL to get last record when using group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get last record of "productID" using group by statement.

The database record:

```
cartID  productID   customerID  quantity    dateAdded   paidStatus
1       20          14          1           2019-03-14  1
2       21          14          1           2019-04-24  1
7       20          16          1           2019-04-25  1
8       20          17          1           2019-04-29  1
11      21          17          2           2019-07-28  1
```

What I tried:SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE productID=20 OR productID=21 GROUP BY productID ORDER BY cartID ASC
```

For current result I get is the first record of `cartID 1` not `8`

The SQL record at below:

```
cartID  productID   customerID  quantity    dateAdded   paidStatus
1       20          14          1           2019-03-14  1
2       21          14          1           2019-04-24  1
```

What I wants:
For some reason I need to get multiple record(by productID) example like `WHERE productID=20 OR WHERE productID=21`

`productID 20` and `21` each having multiple record but

> I need to get the both of last record

The result I needed:

```
cartID  productID   customerID  quantity    dateAdded   paidStatus
8       20          17          1           2019-04-29  1
11      21          17          2           2019-07-28  1
```

Comment: Most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: sorry I was first time using stack overflow to post question

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery for max value group by custome and  product  and join

```
select  a.productId, a.CustomerId, a.quantity, a.dateadded , a.paidstatus 
from my_table a 
inner join  (
  select productId, CustomerId, max(dateadded) max_date
  from my_table  
  group by  productId, CustomerId

) t on t.productId = a.productId
        and t.CustomerId = a.CustomerId
            and t.max_date  = a.dateadded
```

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM cart t
WHERE t.productID IN (20, 21)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM cart
  WHERE productID = t.productID AND dateAdded > t.dateAdded
)
```